# VoiceOver bug with input type date

Tags: html, ios, accessibility, voiceover

I found a new bug with VoiceOver (ios 13.2 & 13.3): I can't open any  with VoiceOver.
(by the way do you have any idea how to report a bug to Apple?)

You can try on this page: https://ideance.net/tests/input-type-date.html.
When the input is focused, I double-tap but nothing happens.

When I put the finger on the  and double-tap, it works!
There is maybe a way to hack this bug but I don't find any solution :(

Do you have any idea?

Comment: I have just tried on my iPhone8 with iOS 13.2.3 and it works fine. A double tap open three fields where I can enter the day, the month and the year, and then close with an OK button.